# Convert ios Swift functions to java(android)

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, data-conversion

I have an ios app working, I am writing same app in android by converting code from swift to java.

I have following functions in swift:

```
func testVibration()
{
var value = getVibrationByte(true)
let data = NSData(bytes: &value, length: sizeof(UInt8))
...
...
}
```

and

```
private func getVibrationByte() -> UInt8
{
   //here I have some conditions to determine below value variable, but those I those I managed to convert, so directly providing 128 value.
    var value = 128
    return UInt8((value + 2 << 2) + 1)
}
```

My query is:

I converted below line:

```
 let data = NSData(bytes: &value, length: sizeof(UInt8))
```

As

```
byte[] data = ByteBuffer.allocate(1).putInt(value).array();
```

Is this correct ? because I am getting "Application Not Responding" error at this line. If not what should be the correct conversion in java for above swift line.

I have tried so many things whole day but no luck.

Comment: I think you should perform this task inside background thread.

Comment: Is this conversion from swift to java is correct ?

Comment: long[] data={value};

Comment: @AndreClassen...Thanks so much ...It worked like charm...you can post it as answer, I will accept that.

Answer (score 0):

hence you are store the data and it's data type will be long as follows

```
long[] data = ByteBuffer.allocate(1).putInt(value).array();
```